# Working with Shopping cart in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, shopping-cart

I have masterpage which has header and footer and the content page contains the list of products and it also has quantities associated with each products, whenever user changes the quantities, prices are updated accordingly

Its all working fine, now i also have an add button associated with each product, whenever user clicks on add button i want to add the product to cart, and it should be available in the list which is on the page's footer section

This all should happen using Ajax without postbacks

My questions are:

1. i am stuck at the logic about the working of shopping cart.
2. I am unable to show the products at the footer of the masterpage once user clicks add on the product, because page does not postbacks to allow me adding products at the footer, as i require jquery to add products.

Can anyone help me about the above 2 issues.

Answer (score 0):

0.. You have to choose the way to store cart items first. You can do that on client side in cookies or on server side in session or db. Doing that on client side may be more difficult because except id of added to cart article and number of each article you also have to dynamically display names of articles, load images from their's urls... So you probably will need to make ajax http get requests to get that additional details about cart items or store them somehow at page. I personally do not prefer this approach. If you choose storing cart information on server (the way I prefer) you have to add js/C# pairs of methods to add/remove items to/from cart. Method that adds item to cart by it's id may also return all information about the item that is required to display item in the cart. For example js may look like:

```
function addItem(id) {
  $.post(
    '/add-item',
    { id: id },
    function (addedItemInfoJson) {
      // display item in cart
    }
  );
}
```

1.. Using approach chosen at step 0 you always have stored items. Then you have to write js function that will get that items from server or from cookies and display it where you need it. So you can just use that function to sync displaying data with what you really have in your storage. So, after you add, remove or increase/decrease number of items you just can call that function.

2.. I can see no problems with this.

Ask if I missed something.